# Calculating the SLL of an antenna array of 8 elements

Tags: antenna, antenna-array

I'm given an array of 8 half-wave dipoles separated 0.15m each and I'm told to calculate the SLL in dB (the ratio between main and secondary lobes). The thing is that The only formula that comes across my mind that could solve the problem is:

[image]

But I think I miss the wavelength in order to use this approach. I'd appreciate any other approach that was able to solve it.

Comment: For an unweighted, or uniform amplitude weighted array, isn't the first sidelobe just 13 dB down from the peak of the main beam?